# ExtJs 3 grid performance issues

Tags: performance, extjs, extjs3

I have a grid panel with about one hundred rows.
On grid's store *load* event a lot of calculations happen that update store rows.
Each update of store row leads to grid row refresh and DOM modifications and this leads to explorer's "Stop running this script?" message.

I'm looking for a way to improve the performance of this code.
Is there any way to suspend DOM operations for the grid in ExtJs 3  - something like suspendLayout, resumeLayout in ExtJs 4?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19540923/extjs-4-1-0-grid-performance-issue
You can check this.